# How to change Windows 8 boot logo (OEM style)?

Tags: windows-8, boot

I know HP, Lenovo, Dell, etc. change the Windows 8 boot logo to match their logo. I would like to do that for a custom-made computer that I built running Windows 8. I'm not refering to the BIOS screen since that can't be changed easily. I'm talking about the logo that appears while Windows 8 is loading. For those of you that don't know, added in Windows 8 was an option for OEMs to customize the boot screen but I don't know where it is.

[image: Windows 8 startup screen]

Comment: "... with my own certificate" - And will such a self-signed bootres.dll be accepted by the OS?

Comment: my certificate is added to the root store, so it should, just like my own drivers are already accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Logo is stored inside the UEFI. So you can't change it. You need to disable the GOP support and [hack several system files to replace the Logo](http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/36724-windows-8-custom-boot-logo/page-2#entry321171)

Comment: Would be as hard to replace the logo in UEFI as it would be to replace a BIOS startup logo?

Comment: Try this tool: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=20829&lang=eng, but I don't know if it works.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to create an EFI application which temporarily modifies the ACPI tables (including BGRT) and then proceeds to load the actual Windows boot manager. This application must then be booted instead of the original Windows boot manager (bootmgfw.efi). BGRT uses the common BMP format (Windows 3.x BMP, or BMP3) with 24-bit or 32-bit colors.

I've created [HackBGRT](https://metabolix.dy.fi/ohjelmointi/esimerkit/HackBGRT/), which is a simple EFI application for the purpose. HackBGRT reads its configuration file, loads the specified BMP to BGRT, sets the coordinates appropriately and loads another EFI application (usually the Windows boot manager, bootmgfw.efi).

The [Clover EFI bootloader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/) can also modify ACPI tables, but it's far more complicated, and I'm not positive if you can actually change the BGRT image with it.

Intel has released some tools which apparently may be used for modifying the BGRT on some motherboards. I'm not aware of any other tools for specifically modifying BGRT.

For non-UEFI systems (or possibly for UEFI systems without BGRT), you can use the various bootres.dll hacks found on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about UEFI logos, since mine is not with that, but I tried [8oot Logo Changer](http://codigobit.net/app/2) and works perfectly and it seems that it does exactly what the hack mentioned above.

Comment: Does it work with automated deployment somehow?

Comment: I get a Chrome warning about malicious software on this link.  Anyone else?

Comment: Yup, chrome warned about malware. Looked into it, it might not be the actual software being malware, but the site it's hosted on. It seems like the server it was hosted was infected, including multiple sites.

Comment: The mirror was clean though. Chrome was happy with it. Putting through some more intensive scans. EDIT: Here are the results- https://www.metascan-online.com/#!/results/file/d3532a76c4814613ab51aee83e148693/regular https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/bfca2d3dfd6a9438599bb684f8d11f2d42689f11c88e6988e3f219bc6dbc96cf/analysis/ Seems legit..