# Is there a way to change BIOS boot screen?

Tags: boot, bios

Here's the thing.
I've already read this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/648471/how-to-change-windows-8-boot-logo-oem-style) about changing boot logo, but I want to change another one.
I'm talking about that logo:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: The logo in question has nothing to do with Windows.  This specific logo is handled by the firmware on the motherboard.   It normally isn't configurable.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. But there's updates for motherboard firmware. So maybe it possible to make the custom update for it.

Comment: Most hardware like this only accepts signed firmware.  In this case unless Lenovo supplies a tool t do this, your unlikely to find a method that works, there is no specific answer to this question every OEM is different.

Comment: IIRC, there used to be some motherboards that supported what you want, but that was long before UEFI came along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr: If you have to ask, the answer is No.**

---

It's possible, but it's going to be both difficult and dangerous.

You would have to:

1) Extract your BIOS

2) Decrypt and unpack it

3) Modify the image

4) Repack and checksum it

5) Reflash your BIOS

All the while praying you have made no mistakes at any step, because doing so will render your computer unusable without physically unsoldering the BIOS chip.

There *are* communities of experts out there who modify laptop BIOS' for fun and profit, and some of them may know the specific procedures for your laptop. But even then, it's risky business.